# Latex: Custom ToC, LoF, LoT for Thesis

Tags: table-of-contents

http://www.sfsu.edu/~gradstdy/forms/thesis-dissertation-sample-pages.pdf

I'm having problems satisfying the Contents page

### Here is what I've tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
...
...


% Set Table of Contents Paramters   
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{0.5in}
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{0.5in}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

% Set List of Figures Parameters    
\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{0.5in}
\setlength{\cftafterloftitleskip}{0.2in}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill\null\\[0.5in]Figure\hfill{Page}}

% Rename Bibliography    
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

% Table of Contents Page    
\tocloftpagestyle{plain}    
{
  \clearpage
  \tableofcontents
  \cleardoublepage
}

% List of Figures Page    
\listoffigures

% List of Appendices Page
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Appendices}
```

---

Q1. How can I say "List of Figures" in the ToC, but have the actual heading on the page to be "LIST OF FIGURES" (all caps)? How do I suppress unwanted header/footer if the list overflows into multiple pages?

Q2. How do I create a similar page for the Appendices?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to address your first "dual" request:

- 'How can I say "List of Figures" in the ToC, but have the actual heading on the page to be "LIST OF FIGURES" (all caps)?'

  Use the following definition for `\cftloftitlefont`:

  ```
  \renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\normalsize\MakeUppercase}
  \renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}%
    \hfill\null\\[0.5in]Figure\hfill{Page}}
  ```

  This works because the LoF title is passed as a single token, which is easily gobbled by `\MakeUppercase`. The addition of `\addcontentsline` in `\cftafterloftitle` inserts the LoF in the ToC.
- 'How do I suppress unwanted header/footer if the list overflows into multiple pages?'

  You can issue a specific page style throughout the entire LoF. While the default for the first page would be `plain`, subsequent pages could also be forced to show up as `plain` (if they don't already). Here's an example that would set the entire LoF using the `mystyle` page style and set it back to `myotherstyle` afterwards:

  ```
  \pagestyle{mystyle}
  \tocloftpagestyle{mystyle}{
    % List of Figures Page
    \listoffigures
    \cleardoublepage
  }
  \pagestyle{myotherstyle}
  ```

For the second request, I suggest completing your current code snippet into something that resembles a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764). Note that there may be packages the influence the appendix (like the [`appendix` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/appendix) or displaying appendices using sections even though the class provides chapters). So, some more information here would be valuable.

Comment: Per your suggestion, I've attached a MEW:
---------------------------------------------

Comment: Oops!
That works. I also have a related question:
Creating a separate page for List of Appendices.
Looking on this website, I found

\newcommand\listappendixname{
  \begin{center}
  \normalsize\MakeUppercase{List of Appendices}
  \end{center}
}
\newcommand\appcaption[1]{%
  \addcontentsline{app}{chapter}{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofappendices{%
  \chapter*{\listappendixname}\@starttoc{app}}
\makeatother
\phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Appendices}
Works, but doesn't look right.
How do I get this new page to have the same top vertical space as List of Fig etc?

Comment: @RamapriyaRangachar: You shouldn't define `\listappendixname` that way. Rather `\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listofappendices}{{\def\contentsname{List of Appendices}\let\old@starttoc\@starttoc\def\@starttoc#1{\old@starttoc{app}}\tableofcontents}}\makeatother` which makes `\listofappendices` duplicate what `\tableofcontents` does, except for the appropriate name changes.